# Replace multiple strings containing $ sign

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I face a problem with regex and string replace and I would love a little bit of help.

I have a string with the following format

```
<div class="$(unique-result) single-result data-index=$(i)"><div class="airport-data data-index=$(i)">$(name)<br>$(city) ,$(country)</div><div class="airport-code data-index=$(i)">$(IATA)</div></div>
```

and I need to replace all the $(unique-result) with a string of mine.

I tried the following code but I can't seem to find out why this doesn't work

```
string.replace(new RegExp('\\$(unique-result)', 'g'), changeString)
```

The result is the exact same string I gave as an input.

Could anyone help me out but also point out why it didn't work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to escape `(` too like this `\(` and same for `)` with `\)`

Comment: I recommend a site like [regexpal](https://www.regexpal.com/) to check your expressions.

Comment: You can also use https://regex101.com/

Comment: And there is no necessarity to use `RegExp` constructor, you can just write your regular expression between slashes `/\$\(unique-result\)/g`

Comment: [`/\$\(unique-result\)/g`](https://regexr.com/47g1c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed escaping. you need to escape properly

```js
let str = `<div class="$(unique-result) single-result data-index=$(i)"><div class="airport-data data-index=$(i)">$(name)<br>$(city) ,$(country)</div><div class="airport-code data-index=$(i)">$(IATA)</div></div>`

let op = str.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\(unique-result\\)','g'), 'Changed')

console.log(op)
```

In case i am not using any variable i prefer using [regex literal (//)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```js
let str = `<div class="$(unique-result) single-result data-index=$(i)"><div class="airport-data data-index=$(i)">$(name)<br>$(city) ,$(country)</div><div class="airport-code data-index=$(i)">$(IATA)</div></div>`

let op = str.replace(/\$\(unique-result\)/g, 'Changed')

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more general solution.

First of all, as I mentioned in comments, you don't need to use the `RegExp` constructor, you can simply pass your regexp between slashes and use flags after last slash:

```
str.replace(/\$\(unique-result\)/g, "someValue")
```

The second moment is that `String.prototype.replace` can accept a function as a second parameter. This will be helpful when there is a lot of named templates in you string. For example, you have the next incoming string:

```
var incomingString = "$(first-value) says $(second-value) when there is $(third-value)"
```

With code that you've provided you should call `replace` 3 times. But if you will use a function as a second parameter, this can be simplified to:

```js
var incomingString = "$(first-value) says $(second-value) when there is $(third-value)"
var data = {
  "first-value": "Kappa",
  "second-value": "Hey!",
  "third-value": "GreyFaceNoSpace"
}
var resultString = incomingString.replace(/\$\(([^)]+)\)/g, (match, capture) => {
  console.log(match, capture)
  return data[capture]
})
console.log(resultString)
```

"WHAT IS GOING ON HERE?!" you will probably ask. Nothing complex.

1. Function that is passed as argument accepts **one or more** arguments: first is a full match and the others are captured groups. It should return the string, that should replace the **full match**.
2. In our regular expression we described that we want to match all possible substrings in format `\$\(([^)]+)\)`, where `[^)]+` refers to **one-or-more-of-any-symbols-except-a-closing-bracket**, and this construction should be captured (it is between not-sanitized brackets).

So, once this regexp will match, it will pass the whole `$(...)` construction into `match` argument of passed function, and the name of the template into `capture` argument. So `capture` is our key for some data storage and we just returning this value in the function.

That's it! Hope, this will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to make the substitution. Match every `$(string)` and apply a function to replace it with a variable stored in an object. Easy and extensible.

```js
const tpl = '<div class="$(unique-result) single-result data-index=$(i)"><div class="airport-data data-index=$(i)">$(name)<br>$(city) ,$(country)</div><div class="airport-code data-index=$(i)">$(IATA)</div></div>';

const vars = {
  i : 9,
  'unique-result' : 'uniq',
  country : 'gb',
  city : 'Manchester',
  IATA : 'MCH'
};

const replaceVars = (tpl,vars) => {
  const replacer = (m, m1) =>
      typeof vars[m1] != 'undefined' ? vars[m1] : '';
  return tpl.replace(/\$\(([\w-]+)\)/g, replacer);
};

console.log(replaceVars(tpl,vars));
```